# Unable to reverse ElementCollection with OxyPlot Series

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, reverse, oxyplot

I need to reverse an ElementCollection of type Series (OxyPlot.Series).
Reverse()-functoin give an ambiguous msg because I can use System.Linq.Enumarable.Reverse or OxyPlot.EnumerableExtensions.Reverse. Both do NOT reverse my ElementCollection.

```
OxyPlot.EnumerableExtensions.Reverse<Series>(lineseries);
System.Linq.Enumerable.Reverse<Series>(lineseries);
```

!! lineseries is a ElementCollection so just the name..not a lineSeries

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `lineseries.Points.Reverse();`

I've tried it and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

With OxyPlot LineSeries Binding, you can modify the ObservableCollection and reverse it.

```
    <oxy:Plot x:Name="P6" Title="Paddle Graph 6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
       <oxy:Plot.Series>
          <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Points}"/>
        </oxy:Plot.Series>
    </oxy:Plot>
```

And your observable collection :

```
    Points = new ObservableCollection<DataPoint>();
    Points.Reverse();
```